# Correct use of HandleScope in Asynchronous Addon

Tags: node.js, v8

I'm writing a asynchronous Node Addon, but I have been struggling to figure out if I need to use a HandleScope in the "After" function that calls the client JavaScript callback.  I've seen examples showing with and without new scopes, but never any explanation why.  Here is an example:

```
void asyncWorkAfter(uv_work_t* req) {
   HandleScope scope; // <-- Do you need a new scope?

   const int argc = 1;
   Local<Value> foo = String::New("foo");
   Local<Value> argv[] = { foo };

   // assume I got my callback function out of req
   callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), argc,  argv);

   callback.Dispose();

   // if i use a new HandleScope, what happens to argv when we go out of scope?
   // Do i need to do something like a scope.Close() to copy argv to the parent scope?
}
```

Do you need/want a HandleScope when you call the callback?
What happens to argv in the example if you do use a new  HandleScope?

Comment: My understaning is that you need HandleScope every time you use Local, that allows locals to be collected properly.

Answer (score 1):

`String::New("foo")` will allocate something on heap and return a handle, so you need to free the memory referenced by this handle some how. If you attach them to a `HandleScope` v8 will do that for you once all references are counted to zero.

> Local handles are held on a stack and are deleted when the appropriate
>   destructor is called. These handles' lifetime is determined by a
>   handle scope, which is often created at the beginning of a function
>   call. When the handle scope is deleted, the garbage collector is free
>   to deallocate those objects previously referenced by handles in the
>   handle scope, provided they are no longer accessible from JavaScript
>   or other handles.

https://developers.google.com/v8/embed